# Mathematical periodic turns in DNA

Tags: dna, theoretical-biology

Today our college professor gave us a mathematical biological challenge in DNA. He challenged us to find the pattern in which DNA follows the following equation in its periodic turn. How can we crack this? Also,  forgive me if I have gone against community guidelines; it’s my first time posting a question.

Here is the equation:

$$2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$$

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! Can you please elaborate more on the context of your question? What is the overall topic in which you've encountered this expression? Was it DNA sequencing, X-ray crystallography ...? What is a "periodic turn in DNA"?

Comment: A hint is that you don't have an *equation*, you have an *expression*. So you could rephrase your question as, *what does this expression equal to, in the context of DNA structural biology?* (I say it's a hint but to be clear; I haven't figured out the answer. Is it actually related to **sequencing** as you tag?)

Comment: My personal opinion is that we'd need a bit more context for this to be on-topic here; we're not after solving riddles and puzzles but about understanding biology. So, if you want to understand *why* a particular expression is used in some particular biological context, that would be very much on topic.

Comment: Thank you, @Domen, The topic at the instance was DNA sequencing; that is why I tagged DNA- sequencing, though the challenge is out of unit course work, as the college professor indicated. It is an expression. I have rephrased the question to English as a secondary language. At that instance, he described how a mathematical transformation can describe the turn from a set of base pair nucleotides to another and inverse periodically; he talked about a sinusoidal wave pattern as an example; he wrote the expression.

Comment: I would start by plotting the expression as a function of n if you don't have an intrinsic intuition of what it would look like. Then I'd check your language and terminology carefully, it seems like a lot is being lost in the translation. Phrases I'd check carefully would include "in its periodic turn" and "DNA follows".

Comment: If it's of any help $(-1)^n$ will *flip-flop* between $+1$ and $-1$. Is there anything in DNA that *cycles* back and forth like that? $-1 \leq \sin \theta \leq +1$. The denominator has $2n + 1$ which always evaluates to an *odd number*. The first term in the series is $1$. The second is $-1/9$. The third is $1/25$. The fourth is $-1/49$. We're, it seems, *converging* to "something".

Comment: To anyone wondering, the value of the expression is $2K\approx 1.832$, where $K$ is the [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Comment: @Domen, while researching the Catalan’s constant I found out that it is used in calculating of volume of the complement of the Borromean rings. where else physical instances of the Borromean rings have been made from linked DNA molecules.